check the query log of postgresql
I want to check the query log of postgresql in real time.
(For your information, I'm currently using docker)
This is my first time viewing the query log, but I'm having a hard time because I can't see the latest information
Can you help me by any chance?
I desperately need your help

There is no reason why logs would be delayed or batched unless the tool you are using to view them is doing so.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@RichardHuxton I didn't have enough explanation
I changed the container settings on the docker so I can check the logs!
Thank you for your interest
